# What results Oracle "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" error on table creation?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to create an Oracle 11g table, but for some reason it says that parenthesis is missing.

```
CREATE TABLE logentry (
        id CHAR(36) NOT NULL, 
        "user" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR), 
        timestamp DATE NOT NULL, 
        description VARCHAR2(32 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
        details TEXT(4096), 
        attn SMALLINT, 
        readonly SMALLINT, 
        hasdata SMALLINT, 
        task_id CHAR(36), 
        "_type" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has no `TEXT` data type. If you need to store amount of character data greater than 4000, you could use `CLOB`(character large object) data type, which will allows you to store up to 4GB of data:

```
CREATE TABLE logentry (
   id          CHAR(36) NOT NULL, 
   "user"      VARCHAR2(8 CHAR), 
   timestamp   DATE NOT NULL, 
   description VARCHAR2(32 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
   details     CLOB, 
   attn        SMALLINT, 
   readonly    SMALLINT, 
   hasdata     SMALLINT, 
   task_id     CHAR(36), 
   "_type"     VARCHAR2(32 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```